# How to override/extend base layout file via Module in magento2?

Tags: magento2, price, overrides

How can we override/ extend a base layout file via **Module** in Magento2? For example, I need to override the "**catalog_product_prices.xml**" from

```
module-catalog/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml
```

to my module say "Mynamespace_Mymodule"?

The content of xml file is

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
            <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Mymodule_CustomPrice::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

And here is the image of my folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to just create below path,

```
Mynamespace_Mymodule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml
```

You have to create directory structure same as core module in your Custom module and do changes in xml file.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh
I have created the file under Mynamespace_CustomPrice/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml and changed the phtml in the xml as <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">MynameSpace_CustomPrice::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>

But it is not taking. Can I include the "base" folder there?

Comment: please post your full code of xml

Comment: Hi @Rakesh,

iI have updated the question. Please have alook

Comment: which line you have override from core file?

Comment: Have you keep at start of xml file, <?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: Yes,  <?xml version="1.0"?> is already there., I need the override on
<item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Mymodule_CustomPrice::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>

Comment: I need to replace the default.phtml with my own file

Comment: Have you not keep phtml file at your theme location, if not then you have to keep in your module with same path.

Comment: I have keep the phtml file in my module as explained in screen shot. Is that is correct?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: Did you get any chance to override a "base" layout file in your projects?

Comment: @VarunJyothi I am facing the same issue, did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya  tried all the things but no luck